# How to best structure this API to store generic delegates for later execution

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, reflection, delegates

I have a custom MVC framework in which I'm overhauling the routing API. I'm trying to think of a clean way to segregate "setup" and "execution" in my framework which makes extensive use of delegates and generics. Right now I envision this from the calling side:

```
//setup
MyRouter.AddRoute("/foo", () => new MyHandler(), (h) => h.MyMethod);
//h.MyMethod only exists in MyHandler, not in HttpHandler
//execution
MyRouter.Execute(HttpContext);
```

I can make the AddRoute method signature "work" currently:

```
delegate T HandlerInvoker<T>();
delegate string HandlerCallMethod<T>(T handler);
...
public void AddRoute<T>(string pattern, HandlerInvoker<T> invoker, HandlerCallMethod<T> caller) where T is HttpHandler{...}
```

If I didn't need to store the invoker and caller and could do it all right then, this would work fine. But, I do need to store the invoker and caller to later execute.

Current things I've thought about doing:

- Storing them in a `List<object>` and then using reflection to call them. This seems extremely complicated and probably not too good of performance
- Moving `AddRoute` to execution. This can make it harder for people using my API, but might end up being my only "good" choice
- Ask a SO question :)

Is there any good way of storing these generic types without a ton of painful reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store an anonymous delegate that performs all the conversion for you.

It looks like the following would work (not tested in any way):

```
List<Action> handlers;
handlers.Add(() => caller(invoker()));
```

Note that this wouldn't work if you were caching `invoker`.

In that case you need to make preserve the value, `Lazy` should do the trick.

```
List<Action> handlers;
Lazy<T> lazy = new Lazy<T>(invoker);
handlers.Add(() => caller(lazy.Value);
```

That latter will only create one instance of the return value of `invoker` per call to the method. And since `lazy` is a local variable, it is automatically shoved into a class which is held onto as long as `handlers` holds onto a reference for you.

Note that I ignored pattern, but it seems you don't need any help there.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to your first method. Creating a delegate which did `var h=invoker(); ... h.Foo="bar" etc.. caller(h)`